# Express a 3-form as a 2-form through a change of coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, volume, exterior-algebra

Given a volume form in $\mathbb{R}^3$
$$vol = x_1\wedge x_2\wedge x_3$$
then by introducing the new variables $y_{ij} = x_ix_j$ is it possible to express this as a 2-form in the $x_i$ and $y_{ij}$ coordinates?

E.g. something like
$$vol = \sum_{ij} f_{ij}\, dz_{i}\wedge dz_j$$
where $z=(x_1,x_2,x_3,y_{11},y_{12},y_{13},y_{22},y_{23},y_{33})$

Comment: Do you mean $dx_i$ instead of just $x_i$'s? (And it is impossible to express a 3-form as a 2-forms in any coordinates)

Comment: A 3-form is a function that takes 3 vectors and outputs a number.  The only way you could rewrite that as a 2-form would be if the 3-form has redundancy in it and even then I am not sure it would work.  You certainly can't do it in general.

Comment: hmm ok, maybe what I'm asking is straight up impossible then. By introducing the variables $y_{ij}$, we go from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^9$. I thought that there might be a way to express the 3-from in  $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a 2-form in $\mathbb{R}^9$ but I don't really know my diff forms very well.